# csv import null value powershell script

Tags: powershell, null, ssms, import-csv

i have created a table called KS_Invoicing, however the following powershell script wont allow me to import NULL values. any ideas why?

```
$database = 'Database'
$server = '192.168.1.1'
$table = 'KS_Invoicing'
$path = '\\hmks01\c$\temp\'

$CSVs = get-childitem $path -Filter *.csv
foreach ($c in $CSVs){

Import-CSV $path$c | ForEach-Object { 
$_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {$_.Value = $_.Value.Trim()} 

$column1= $_."Column One" 

if ($column1) {

$query= "insert into "+$table+" VALUES ('"+$column1+"')"  

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query $query -U ks  -Password ks2020
}

}
Move-Item $path$c "\\hmks01\c$\temp\Archive"
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert value "" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:12 char:1
+ $column1= $_."Column One" 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: I don't see where the `System.DateTime` is comming from. Did you execute the code in a fresh Powershell session or have some of the variables been used before? To me it looks like `$_."Column One" ` is an empty string ( `""` not `$NULL`) and `$column1` is of type `System.DateTime`...

Comment: it a new powershell window. i have previously used the following but there don't seem to work when the cell in the .csv file is blank

$column1= $_."Column One"  -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ]+'

for datetime $column1= $_."Column One"  -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}///}/_]', ''

Comment: happy for someone to help me create a new .ps script. basically the .csv may have columns with blank data (null value). in the database table the column is set to Allow Nulls

Comment: You are not showing how your CSV is configured. Import-Csv does allow the import of rows with empty fields. This is a common occurrence. I just created a sample file 3 columns, 3 rows, and column 2 is empty and imports just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per my first comment. Importing empty values work as expected.

```
'Field1,Field2,Field3
Row1Field1Data,,Row1Field3Data
Row2Field1Data,,Row2Field3Data
Row3Field1Data,,Row3Field3Data' | 
Out-FIle -FilePath 'D:\Temp\EmptyFields.csv'

psEdit 'D:\Temp\EmptyFields.csv'
# Results
<#
Field1,Field2,Field3
Row1Field1Data,,Row1Field3Data
Row2Field1Data,,Row2Field3Data
Row3Field1Data,,Row3Field3Data
#>

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\EmptyFields.csv'
# Results
<#
Field1         Field2 Field3        
------         ------ ------        
Row1Field1Data        Row1Field3Data
Row2Field1Data        Row2Field3Data
Row3Field1Data        Row3Field3Data
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous reply. If you want to import NULL value, you have to follow this syntax :
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/insert-statement/insert-null.php

So you have to detect empty value in your csv and replace with "NULL".

```
$csv = 'Column One,Column Two,Column Three
Row1Field1Data,,Row1Field3Data
,Row1Field2Data,Row2Field3Data
Row3Field1Data,,Row3Field3Data'  | ConvertFrom-Csv
$table = 'KS_Invoicing'
foreach($line in $csv){
    $values = $line.PSObject.Properties.Value 
    $values | Foreach-Object {$_ = $_.Trim()} 

    $tab = foreach($v in $values)
    {
        if($v -eq ""){'NULL'}
        else{"`"$v`""}
    }
    "insert into $table VALUES ($($tab -join ','))"
}
```